# Dukascopy data downloader github

Tags: python

Hi I downloaded this repository from GitHub( https://github.com/giuse88/duka ) and I successfully pip installed it now I don't know how to access it or use it when I type duka -h it is saying it is not recognized.

Comment: There is no need to download the repository. pip will do it for you. `pip install duka` is enough.

Comment: Add `export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"` to your `~/.bashrc` file.

Comment: which bash file

Comment: I tried to add the package file to environmental variable

Comment: Are you on windows?